# MDX: Recursion over propery

Tags: mdx

When having a dimension [Date] containing dates. The members of this dimension have a property „LastRelevantDate“. I would like to write a mdx query returning the member names which starts at a given Date and iteratively looks up the next member given in the „LastRelevantDate“ property etc. I‘d like this to be repeated x–times. Is this possible with mdx? How could such a query look like?

Answer (score 0):

These functions are iterative in `MDX`:

```
GENERATE

FILTER
```

An example from MSDN for Generate:

```
SELECT   
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}  
ON 0,  
GENERATE(   
[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS  
, TOPCOUNT(  
[Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER  
*  
[Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS  
,10, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]))  
ON 1  
FROM [Adventure Works]
```